# Calcular nueva columna en spark df, cruzando columna de tipo lista en df1 y columna de texto en df2 con pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp

Estoy usando spark 2.4.5 y necesito calcular el score de sentimientos de la **lista de tokens** (columna MeaningfulWords) del **df1**, según las **palabras** y scores del **df2** (diccionario de sentimientos). En Df1 debo crear una nueva columna con la lista de scores de los tokens y otra columna con la media de sentimientos (suma de scores/total palabras) de cada registro.

Los dataframes tienen esta pinta:

```
df1.select("ID","MeaningfulWords").show(truncate=True, n=5)
+------------------+------------------------------+
|                ID|               MeaningfulWords|
+------------------+------------------------------+
|abcde00000qMQ00001|[casa, alejado, buen, gusto...|
|abcde00000qMq00002|[clientes, contentos, servi...|
|abcde00000qMQ00003|                 [resto, bien]|
|abcde00000qMQ00004|[mal, servicio, no, antiend...|
|abcde00000qMq00005|[gestion, adecuada, proble ...|
+------------------+------------------------------+

df2.show(5)
+-----+----------+
|score|      word|
+-----+----------+
| 1.68|abandonado|
| 3.18|    abejas|
|  2.8|    aborto|
| 2.46| abrasador|
| 8.13|    abrazo|
+-----+----------+
```

El resultado de las columnas nuevas, debería ser algo como esto:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
|         MeanScore|            ScoreList|
+------------------+---------------------+
|              2.95|[3.10, 2.50, 1.28,...|
|              2.15|[1.15, 3.50, 2.75,...|
|              2.75|[4.20, 1.00, 1.75,...|
|              3.25|[3.25, 2.50, 3.20,...|
|              3.15|[2.20, 3.10, 1.28,...|
+------------------+---------------------+
```

He revisado varias opciones usando .join, pero al tratarse de tipos de datos diferentes entre las columnas da error.

He revisado opciones como https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576196/joining-pyspark-dataframes-on-nested-field, pero no puedo hacer join directa entre las dos columnas por tener tipos de datos diferentes.

También he probado convirtiendo los Df a RDD y usar una función, así:

```
def map_words_to_values(review_words, afinn_dict):
return [afinn_dict[word] for word in review_words if word in afinn_dict]

RDD1=swRemoved.rdd.map(list) 
RDD2=Dict_df.rdd.map(list)

reviewsRDD_afinn_values = RDD1.map(lambda tupple: (tupple[0], map_words_to_values(tupple[1], RDD2)))
reviewsRDD_afinn_values.take(3)
```

Pero con esta última opción recibo el siguiente error:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Sé como resolverlo con pandas, pero quisiera encontrar la forma correcta de resolverlo con spark sin castigar el rendimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Han resuelto mi problema en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687997/calculate-new-column-in-spark-dataframe-crossing-a-tokens-list-column-in-df1-wi:

Puede hacer esto primero con un `join` usando `array_contains(MeaningfulWords,word)`, luego `groupBy` y `collect_list` de todas las **word** que hicieron `join`, luego usando las funciones de orden superior `transform` y `aggregate` para obtener el score medio (valido en spark2.4+).

La función de orden superior `aggregate` solo acepta valores enteros, por eso fue necesario usar `transform` para convertir, y al final dividir por 100 (Asumiendo un máximo de 2 decimales, p.e. 2.81).

```
df1.show()

#+------------------+----------------------------+
#|ID                |MeaningfulWords             |
#+------------------+----------------------------+
#|abcde00000qMQ00001|[casa, alejado, buen, gusto]|
#|abcde00000qMq00002|[clientes, contentos, servi]|
#|abcde00000qMQ00003|[resto, bien]               |
#+------------------+----------------------------+

df2.show()

#+-----+---------+
#|score|     word|
#+-----+---------+
#| 1.68|     casa|
#|  2.8|  alejado|
#| 1.03|     buen|
#| 3.68|    gusto|
#| 0.68| clientes|
#|  2.1|contentos|
#| 2.68|    servi|
#| 1.18|    resto|
#| 1.98|     bien|
#+-----+---------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1.join(df2, F.expr("""array_contains(MeaningfulWords,word)"""))\
   .groupBy("ID").agg(F.first("MeaningfulWords").alias("MeaningfullWords")\
                      ,F.collect_list("score").alias("ScoreList"))\
   .withColumn("MeanScore", F.expr("""aggregate((transform(ScoreList,x->int(x*100)))\
                                      ,0,(x,acc)-> acc+x,acc->(acc/100)/ size(Scorelist))""")).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------+
#|ID                |MeaningfullWords            |ScoreList              |MeanScore|
#+------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------+
#|abcde00000qMQ00003|[resto, bien]               |[1.18, 1.98]           |1.58     |
#|abcde00000qMq00002|[clientes, contentos, servi]|[0.68, 2.1, 2.68]      |1.82     |
#|abcde00000qMQ00001|[casa, alejado, buen, gusto]|[1.68, 2.8, 1.03, 3.68]|2.2975   |
#+------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+---------+
```